# adding leading zeroes using vb6?

Tags: vb6

I am getting nowhere in my attempts to do this, what i have so far is this,

```
Private Sub Timeperpart_Timer()


    secs = secs + 1
    If secs = 60 Then
    mins = mins + 1
    secs = 0
    End If
    If mins = 60 Then
    hrs = hrs + 1
    mins = 0
    End If

     If secs < 10 Then
           Lbltime.Caption = CStr(hrs & ":" & mins & ":" & 0 & CStr(secs))
           End If

If mins < 10 Then
ElseIf secs < 10 Then
            Lbltime.Caption = CStr(hrs & ":" & 0 & CStr(mins) & ":" & 0 & CStr(secs))
      Else
       Lbltime.Caption = CStr(hrs & ":" & 0 & CStr(mins) & ":" & secs)
       End If

       If hrs < 10 Then
       ElseIf mins < 10 Then
       ElseIf secs < 10 Then
       Lbltime.Caption = CStr(0 & CStr(hrs) & ":" & 0 & CStr(mins) & ":" & 0 & CStr(secs))
       End If

       If hrs < 10 Then
       ElseIf mins < 10 Then
       ElseIf secs > 10 Then

        Lbltime.Caption = CStr(0 & CStr(hrs) & ":" & 0 & CStr(mins) & ":" & secs)
       End If

        If hrs < 10 Then
       ElseIf mins > 10 Then
     ElseIf secs > 10 Then

        Lbltime.Caption = CStr(0 & CStr(hrs) & ":" & mins & ":" & secs)
       End If

End Sub
```

the problem is that in the line `if mins < 10 then` the program wont recognize mins as being less than ten if it is zero and then wont add a leading zero, same with hours. im looking for a way that works or really just any way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace all that code with:

```
Lbltime.Caption = Format$(TimeSerial(hrs, mins, secs), "hh:mm:ss")
```

In fact, also replace all that `hrs` `mins` `secs` addition logic with:

```
Dim the_time As Date
....
the_time = DateAdd("s", 1, the_time)
```

So that in the end you have:

```
Private the_time As Date

Private Sub Timeperpart_Timer()
  the_time = DateAdd("s", 1, the_time)
  Lbltime.Caption = Format$(the_time, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks that really helped, i feel silly using so much code before! ill accept the answer as soon as it lets me!